# c# tryParseExact not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a string that I'm trying to parse.

when I use  `var newDt = Convert.ToDateTime("3/6/2019 12:00:00 AM +00:00");`

It gives me the date with a different timezone. I would get a date time of `3/5/2019 4:00AM`

I would like it to parse and return the same date time as the string.

I've tried

```
var newDt = DateTime.ParseExact("3/6/2019 12:00:00 AM +00:00", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get the error

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

How can I parse the date `"3/6/2019 12:00:00 AM +00:00"` to return a datetime with the same value of 3/6/2019 12AM

Comment: Where do you account for the offset (`+00:00`) in the format? What you've passed and what you told it to expect are not exact.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb That is the part I am confused about. I'm not sure how to account for the `+00:00`. I know the format is wrong but I can't find any references on how to format it.

Comment: Wait a second.. Are you really sure that `Convert.ToDateTime("3/6/2019 12:00:00 AM +00:00")` returns `3/5/2019 4:00AM`? It makes `-32:00` hours offset o.O Maybe it returns `3/6/2019 4:00AM`?

Comment: @SonerGönül Sorry I meant `3/5/2019 4:00PM` not `AM`

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense But that _still_ makes `-20:00` hours offset :\

Comment: @SonerGönül It's definitely returning a `DateTime` object of `3/5/2019 4:00PM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have [UTC−08:00 time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9208:00) (which I assume your `Convert.ToDateTime` code part returns `3/6/2019 4:00AM` not `3/5/2019 4:00AM`) in your machine and that's why when you parse it with offset value, you will get 4 hour added value.

If your string contains [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, it would be better to parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `DateTime`.

```
var newDt = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("3/6/2019 12:00:00 AM +00:00", 
                                      "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt zzz",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can use it's [`.DateTime` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the value you expected.

Comment: Unrelated to this question but I added a link to your profile here in case you’ve had any comments, hopefully it’s ok.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324536/484041

Comment: @bestinamir No problem.